# Why is Set() repeating values?

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to use Set() in js to retrieve some 'unique data', but it keeps returning repeated values to me.

Console debug:
[image: Console debug]

Code:

```
userStories.add({
   user_id: storie.user_id,
   avatar: storie.user.avatar,
});
```

Comment: You are creating a new `Object` in the `add` function

Comment: Hi! Can you please place the code into code blocks and not in screenshots?

Comment: do you know that objects aren't equal?: {} == {} - false, even if they look alike, same in your example they have the same props but they ain't the same objects

Comment: This the expected behavior. Consider using a `Map` keyed by id.

Comment: For that purpose you might be better with a regular object mapping ID to value.

Comment: https://javascript.info/object-copy

Comment: Oh, I forgot JS has those weird casts, thanks everyone.

Comment: You'll find _"those weird casts"_ in most programming languages. This behavior is not specific to JavaScript.

Comment: this is a set of Objects, Object values can be the same, but object elements not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sounds like you are trying to avoid duplicating users?

It is clever to try to use a set, because sets do avoid duplication, but unfortunately they only work in the way you intended if the element is a primitive data type such as `String` or `Number`, and not if it is an object, i.e. of the form `{ key: value, ... }`.

If the element is just a string, e.g. "Bob", because two strings "Bob" and "Bob" are considered identical by the Set, and so will be entered as a single element.

However, if your element is an *object*, e.g. {name: "Bob"}, then two elements defined separately as `{name: "Bob"}` and `{name: "Bob"}` will be considered unequal, so will be entered as two different elements in the Set.

#### Try using a simple Object

Initialise like this:

```
userStories = {}
```

And then for each entry:

```
userStories[user_id]=({
   avatar: storie.user.avatar,
});
```

This way, you end up with this structure:

```
userStories: {
    1234: { avatar: "abc.jpg" },
    1258: { avatar: "def.jpg" },
    etc
}
```

You can use this Object structure in much the way you were using the Set, with two advantages:

(a) If you put in two identical entries such as `1234: { avatar: "abc.jpg" }`, only one will be stored.

(b) You can directly access the avatar of any one person, by their id. (With the Set, you would still have to somehow search the elements to find the right one.)

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript are [reference types](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0), which means that when you create a new object in your function, JavaScript thinks they are different (even when they have the same values).

From the article:

> If they’re distinct objects, even if they contain identical properties, the comparison will result in false.
>
> ```js
> var arr1 = ['Hi!'];
> var arr2 = ['Hi!'];
> console.log(arr1 === arr2); // -> false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or **object references** not just objects. See reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#description)

```
const mySet = new Set();
const object1 = {a:1, b:1};
mySet.add(object1);
mySet.add(object1);
console.log(mySet); // The set will be having only 1 entry as both the times we added the same reference of object1.
```

However if you do try to insert different references of object the set keeps on adding the objects.For example:

```
const mySet = new Set();
const object1 = {a:1, b:1};
mySet.add(object1);
mySet.add({a:1,b:1}); // This is a new object not the object1
console.log(mySet); It will have 2 entries
```

Not only objects same goes with Arrays if you try to do like above.